# allowing user to customize what fields he or she wants for the report in access

Tags: ms-access

I have a report whose record source is query from 6 tables. In the report I have 6 check boxes, one for each table. I would like have the user the ability to click on these checkboxes and the table in subform of the report should display only the fields which belong to those tables (checked ones not the unchecked).

There is a way to do this in query design view by clicking check box for Show and make those fields not appear, but i don't know how to access that property using macro or procedure.

Also note that the Report form has subform which displays the table (query datasheet). Right now this table has like 45 fields, thats why i need the above functionality.

Here is the screenshot of the query (design view), I need to control show property in each column (using VBscript or macro). So I want the user have the ability to choose which columns to appear in the table (subform) of the report.

[image: search query screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue once (with 2003) and found that you can't use the quer designer whilst using runtime mode which is a shame, you could allow your users to run outside of runtime and preset a query as "Snap-shot" so they can only execute a read-only query.  Alternatively you could go the the trouble I did of setting up a custom form with combo boxes to allow table/field selection and then store your table joins in another table, although this will only work if each table is only joined to one other otherwise it will fall apart.

Comment: Is there a way for me to do a query on a query this being done when the user clicks on the check box for a particular table. Since what i have is result of query which is like a table right?

Comment: @nman84 Yes, it would be fine to do it that way and base a query on another query, actually that's better because you only need a form showing the queries fields, maybe as simple as a listbox where users can do a multiple select. Mine was more for if you wanted people to build custom queries from scratch.

Comment: I am new to access i don't know how to do this? I have searchq( query) which produces the table from other tables. How do i do query with list box again and display those results in subform. I just need an example